# How to communicate with modal in bootstrap vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a complex modal that I've put in it's own component. It works on a copy of the passed model, to allow the user to cancel the action.

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    v-if="itemCopy"
    v-model="shown"
    @cancel="$emit('input', null)"
    @ok="$emit('input', itemCopy)"
  >
  <!-- content -->
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      shown: false,
      itemCopy: null
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value(itemToDisplay) {
      this.shown = !!itemToDisplay;
      this.initValue();
    },
    item(it) {
      this.initValue();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initValue() {
      this.itemCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The Idea to communicate with it is to pass an object in the v-model and, if set, the modal will be shown using that data, and when done, the new state will be communicated back over the v-model as well.

That is, if the user cancel/closed the modal, the v-modal variable will be null, otherwise it will be a new Model that will replace the one in v-modal.

```
<template>
  <!-- omitted for brevity -->
  <ItemModal v-model="modalItem" />
<template>
<script>
//...
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemNumber: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    modalItem:{
      get() {
        if (this.itemNumber != null) return this.entries[this.itemNumber];
      },
      set(newItem) {
        if (newItem && this.itemNumber) {
          //splice, etc.
        }
        // in any clase reset the selection to close the modal
        this.itemNumber = null;
      }
    },
//...
<script>
```

The Problem I have is with the events from `b-modal`. I can use the `@ok` but there's no `@notOk`.
For example `@cancel` won't be thrown if the user click outside of the modal.

How can this be achieved? Is there another more easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b-modal` emits a generic `hide` event, which receives as its first argument the trigger that closed the modal (i.e. `ok`, `cancel`, `esc`, `backdrop`, etc):

```html
<template>
  <b-modal
    v-if="itemCopy"
    v-model="shown"
    @hide="handleHide"
  >
  <!-- content -->
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    // ...
    handleHide(bvEvt) {
      if (bvEvt.trigger === 'ok') {
        // User clicked OK button
        this.$emit('input', this.itemCopy)
      } else {
        // The modal was closed not via the `ok` button
        this.$emit('input', null)
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Nice! trigger is actually `bvModalEvent` so better auto unbox `handleHide({trigger}) {` or something the like. Could you please fix that smal thing, so I accept the answer? It's really great, thanks!

Comment: Fixed the example.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<template>
  <b-modal
    :id="id"
    @ok="$emit('ok', item)"
  >
  <!-- content -->
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: Object,
    id: String
  }
};
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <!-- omitted for brevity -->
  <ItemModal :item="modalItem" :id="modalId" @ok="onModalOk" />
<template>
<script>
//...
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      modalId:  "myItemModal"
      itemNumber: null
      modalItem: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showItemModal(itemNumber) {
      this.itemNumber = itemNumber
      this.modalItem = _.cloneDeep(this.entries[itemNumber])
      this.$bvModal.show(this.modalId)
    },
    onModalOk(newItem) {
      if (newItem && this.itemNumber) {
        //splice, etc.
      }
    }
  }
//...
<script>
```

Comment: This is also a nice possibility, encapsulation is not that great but relying on the `$bvModal.show` and passing the id, would indeed work. Thanks!